# Why does my mouse event coordinates return wrong values?

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent

I've got two classes: `Connection extends JComponent` and `PostMachineView extends JPanel implements MouseListener`.
What I'm trying to do is fire a method whenever the mouse button is pressed inside the `Connection` component.
I'm using `SwingUtilities.convertPointToScreen` so that the mouse event coordinates  will be relative to where I am drawing. The problem is that it returns slightly different numbers for `x` and `y` than it should.
Code below:

```
public class PostMachineView extends JPanel implements MouseListener {
    ArrayList<Connection> connections;

    public PostMachineView() {
        connections = new ArrayList<>();
        setSize(new Dimension(800, 800));
        setBackground(Color.white);

        //here i create the points i'll need for the connection and instantiate it
        Point p1 = new Point(100, 100);
        Point p2 = new Point(100, 200);
        Connection conn = new Connection(p1, p2);
        //add the connection component to this panel
        add(conn);
        //set the connection mouse listener
        conn.addMouseListener(this);

        connections.add(conn);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);

        //this will be done in a different way, just trying to get it to work first
         Point p1 = new Point(100, 100);
         Point p2 = new Point(100, 200);

         ((Connection)getComponent(0)).paintComponent(g, p1, p2);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("clicked in the component");
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
}

public class Connection extends JComponent {

    private Rectangle2D.Double curveControl;
    private GeneralPath path;

    public Connection(Point p1, Point p2) {
        path = new GeneralPath();
        path.moveTo(p1.getX(), p1.getY());
        int[] mid = getMidPointCoords(p1, p2);
        curveControl = new Rectangle2D.Double(mid[0] - 5, mid[1] - 5, 10, 10);
        path.curveTo(curveControl.getCenterX(), curveControl.getCenterY(),
                curveControl.getCenterX(), curveControl.getCenterY(),
                p2.getX(), p2.getY());

    }
    public int[] getMidPointCoords(Point p1, Point p2) {
        int[] v = { 0, 0 };
        v[0] = (int) ((p1.getX() + p2.getX()) / 2);
        v[1] = (int) ((p1.getY() + p2.getY()) / 2);
        return v;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g, Point p1, Point p2) {
        path.moveTo(p1.getX(), p1.getY());
        path.curveTo(curveControl.getCenterX(), curveControl.getCenterY(),
                curveControl.getCenterX(), curveControl.getCenterY(),
                p2.getX(), p2.getY());

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2d.draw(path);
        g2d.setColor(Color.red);
        g2d.fill(curveControl);
        g2d.setColor(Color.black);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(int x, int y) {
    //here is where i use swingutilities to convert the coordinates
        Point p = new Point(x, y);
        SwingUtilities.convertPointToScreen(p, this);
        return curveControl.contains(p.getX(), p.getY());
    }
}
```

I also have a Teste class, which simply instantiates a JFrame and adds a `PostMachineView` to it:

```
public class Teste  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setSize(new Dimension(800,800));
        f.add(new PostMachineView());
        f.setResizable(false);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: *" I'm using SwingUtilities.convertPointToScreen so that the mouse event coordinates will be relative to where I am drawing"* - That's actually incorrect.  The coordinates will be relative to the current screen (top/left corner of the screen), where `0x0` in your component will be the top/left position of the component

Comment: Don't paint `Connection` from `PostMachineView`, this just doesn't make sense, since connection is a child of `PostMachineView`, you should just call `repaint` when you want it updated

Comment: When i want a Connection updated i should call repaint in PostMachineView, is that it?

Comment: You add the `MouseListener` to `Connection` so ALL the `MouseEvents` will already be translated to the `Connection`'s context

Comment: How do I get the right coordinates?

Comment: Since the `MouseListener` is attached to the `Connection`, they are already within the `Connection`'s coordinate context

Answer (score 2):

This...

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);

    //this will be done in a different way, just trying to get it to work first
     Point p1 = new Point(100, 100);
     Point p2 = new Point(100, 200);

     ((Connection)getComponent(0)).paintComponent(g, p1, p2);
}
```

Is a VERY bad idea.  The `Connection` component is already a child of the `PostMachineView` component.  You should simply be updating the state of `Connection` (maybe through a `mouseClicked` event) and calling `repaint` to update it.

In `Connection`, this...

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g, Point p1, Point p2) {
    path.moveTo(p1.getX(), p1.getY());
    path.curveTo(curveControl.getCenterX(), curveControl.getCenterY(),
            curveControl.getCenterX(), curveControl.getCenterY(),
            p2.getX(), p2.getY());

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

    g2d.draw(path);
    g2d.setColor(Color.red);
    g2d.fill(curveControl);
    g2d.setColor(Color.black);
}
```

Should be slit into two methods, one that adds the new point and one that draws it...

```
public void add(Point p1, Point p2) {
    path.moveTo(p1.getX(), p1.getY());
    path.curveTo(curveControl.getCenterX(), curveControl.getCenterY(),
                    curveControl.getCenterX(), curveControl.getCenterY(),
                    p2.getX(), p2.getY());
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
    g2d.draw(path);
    g2d.setColor(Color.red);
    g2d.fill(curveControl);
    g2d.setColor(Color.black);
    g2d.dispose();
}
```

Because the `MouseListener` is attached to the `Connection` component, this...

```
@Override
public boolean contains(int x, int y) {
//here is where i use swingutilities to convert the coordinates
    Point p = new Point(x, y);
    SwingUtilities.convertPointToScreen(p, this);
    return curveControl.contains(p.getX(), p.getY());
}
```

No longer makes sense and, to be honest, I'd be VERY careful with messing around with this

At best it should be more like...

```
public boolean contains(int x, int y) {
    return curveControl.contains(x, y);
}
```

But remember, the `MouseListener` will no longer generate events unless the x/y coordinates are WITHIN the `curveControl`, which might not really be what you want.

Oh and this `ArrayList<Connection> connections;` scares me...but then, I don't have the context to your problem to really know what you're intentions are for this...

Comment: Well, this project was a bad idea at all... I could not get it to work because of some troubles with layoutmanager after changing a few things that you pointed out. I ended up giving up on the whole thing and creating a new project - which has been working just fine, surprising me. I'm using a Canvas object to draw classes that extend Path2D.Double and Polygon. Thanks for everything :)